# How to make api call that requires login in web2py?

Tags: python, api, urllib2, web2py, urllib

I want to access APIs from application. Those APIs has decorator `@auth.requires_login()`.

I am calling api from controller using

**demo_app/controllers/plugin_task/task**

```
url = request.env.http_origin + URL('api', 'bind_task')
page = urllib2.Request(url)
page.add_header('cookie', request.env.http_cookie)
response = urllib2.urlopen(page)
```

Demo API

**api.py**

```
@auth.requires_login()
@request.restful()
def bind_task():
    response.view = 'generic.json'
    return dict(GET=_bind_task)


def _bind_task(**get_params):
    return json.dumps({'status': '200'})
```

Above code gives me error : `HTTPError: HTTP Error 401: UNAUTHORIZED`
How to solve this issue? I need to add any other headers?

**Directory structure-**

```
Demo_app
|
|-controllers
   |
   |-api.py 
   |-plugin_task.py
```

controller `plugin_task.py` calls `bind_task()` which is in `api.py`

**EDIT:**

Application .w2p file- [Download](https://www.dropbox.com/s/f54s0iqjn9a6wwz/web2py.app.welcome.w2p?dl=0)

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem. Is that your exact code? Can you show the rest of the controller code (i.e., how `url` is constructed and what you do with the response to return it)? Is the calling controller in the same app as the API?

Comment: @Anthony Updated question and added how url is built. Calling controller is plugin controller and its in same app. Also added directory structure in question.

Comment: What is the value of `request.env.http_origin`, and what does the final URL end up looking like?

Comment: @Anthony value of  request.env.http_origin is `http://127.0.0.1:8000`. And final url is `http://127.0.0.1:8000/Demo_app/api/bind_task` . `Demo_app` is my application name!

Comment: The URL looks correct, though if you want an absolute URL, you should instead use `URL('api', 'bind_task', host=True, scheme=True)`. Anyway, still can't reproduce the problem. Maybe go to the Google Group and post a minimal app that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @Anthony Thanks for help. When I enter above url in browser , it returns `{'status': '200'}` without any issue. But I try to do it through code it gives error. Inside api function `auth.is_logged_in()` returns `False` and inside controller it returns `True`. If I remove `@auth.requires_login()` decorator , then it works fine. Any help?

Comment: Sorry, your code works for me. All I can suggest is to post a full app.

Comment: Thank you for help. I will put question in google group with app.

Comment: @Anthony Added full app in question. Please help to solve this issue. [.w2p file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/f54s0iqjn9a6wwz/web2py.app.welcome.w2p?dl=0)

Comment: The app you posted does not use the code shown above (which is commented out), but incorrect code that fails to set the cookie. When removing the incorrect code and instead uncommenting the code you have shown above, everything works fine. Is that not the case for you?

Comment: @Anthony When I use commented code(given in question),  my command line freezes and application web page doesn't responds. If I use uncommented code,  it gives unauthorized error. I am using web2py-2.3.2 . I am referring [HOWTO Fetch Internet Resources Using urllib2](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/urllib2.html#data)

Comment: It works for me, so I assume the problem is related to your deployment. Please explain how you are running web2py. Also, you might consider upgrading, as your version of web2py is three years old.

Comment: @Anthony I am testing it on local machine. I run web2py using command `python web2py.py -p 8000 -a pass123` and access application from browser using `http://127.0.0.1:8000/welcome/` .  And We are planning to upgrade web2py . But for now I have to use 2.3.2 :) .

Comment: I'm curious to see what happens when you upgrade. If you're running locally, you can try with the latest web2py very easily -- just download and unzip, then copy your application folder.

Comment: @Anthony I tested it on `web2py 2.12.3 stable` and `web2py 2.9.12 stable`. It gave me same output, if I use commented code then command line freezes and if I use uncommented code then it gives error `HTTP Error 401: UNAUTHORIZED`. If I test application without logging then both cases gives above error.  I am using Python 2.7.6, Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, urllib 1.17 and urllib2 2.7 .  Please help!

Comment: I would suggesting moving to the Google Group. Post the app there (using the commented code, as that is the proper method) with details about your setup and the exact workflow that is leading to the error (along with the exact traceback or response). Also, if you are able, maybe try it on Windows or OSX.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that [this](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/10/services#Restful-Web-Services) is the proper way to specify the REST API endpoint in Web2py:

```py
auth.settings.allow_basic_login = True
@auth.requires_login()
@request.restful()
def api():
    response.view = 'generic.json'

    def GET(tablename, id):
        if not tablename == 'person':
            raise HTTP(400)
        return dict(person = db.person(id))

    def POST(tablename, **fields):
        if not tablename == 'person':
            raise HTTP(400)
        return db.person.validate_and_insert(**fields)

    return locals()
```

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46658600), that `@auth.requires_login()` decorator uses HTTPBasicAuth, which is [easy to use](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/authentication/) after `python -m pip install requests`:

```py
import requests


requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/myapp/default/api/person/1.json', auth=('user', 'pass'))
```