# Restful API with authentication

Tags: web2py

I try to built an API for my web2py application.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
auth.settings.allow_basic_login = True

@auth.requires_login()
@request.restful()
def api():
    response.view = 'generic.json'

    def GET(tablename, id):
        if not tablename == 'division':
            raise HTTP(400)


        result = db(db.division.title == id).select()

        return dict(result = result)

return locals()
```

But everytime I try to connect via curl I get this answer:

```
You are being redirected <a href=\"/my_manager/login?_next=/my_manager/api/get_all_divisions/1.json\">here</a>
```

When I comment out this line

```
@auth.requires_login()
```

everythink works fine.

I've searched for hints, but didn't found any helpful information about this topic so far.

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: What does your curl call look like? Are you sure you are passing valid login credentials?

Comment: @sarah I faced similar issue, still waiting for the solution. I posted one question about this, you might get some help from comments or my code. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33938076/how-to-make-api-call-that-requires-login-in-web2py

Comment: @Anthony I tried with the example from the web2py book and I'm sure that the login data is correct. My login is with an email address and password

Comment: @GauravVichare Thanks, I've seen your thread during my research to this topic.

Comment: @SarahWest, what does your curl request look like?

Comment: `curl --user sw@mymail.com:mypasswd http://127.0.0.1:8000/my_manager/api/api/1`

Comment: it works when I comment out `@auth.requires_login()` and use `curl`without `--user`

Answer (score 1):

I know its a pretty old question but still this answer will help other people who might experience same issue:

Well in your case you are using `@auth.requires_login()` which needs user to be logged in.

So you need to send basic auth credentials while making calls to this api.

A simplest curl call can be:

```
curl --user abc@example.com:abc123 http://localhost:8000/app_name/default/api/table_name.json
```

Here:

- abc@example.com is username
- abc123 is password
- app_name is the web2py's app name
- table_name is the table name in db